# Docker deployment of dot net core application which is consuming NAV soap endpoint gives error The HTTP request is unauthorized

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, asp.net-core-3.1, dynamics-nav

I have dot net core application 3.1 which is consuming NAV soap endpoint, consuming NAV soap endpoint working fine in IIS deployment but failing in docker deployment.

Previously there was an error
GSSAPI operation failed with error - Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information (Cannot find KDC for realm "Example.com")

After applying
AppContext.SetSwitch("System.Net.Http.UseSocketsHttpHandler", false);
Error --The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Basic'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate'

Comment: Nav can use ntlm or negotiate/cerberos authentication, you are sending basic one. It’s not gonna work. Locally you most probably using ntlm and it works. When deploying to docker you must be misconfiguring iis and it sends basic requests.